# how to select orders which have same items sku and qty?

Tags: mysql

I have orders and purchased product tables in joins.

how can I select the orders which have same SKU and qty and same items count in purchased products table?

let's say I select the oldest order first with id 1 in orders table below and it should get all the purchased items from purchased product table(A B and C) with that reference it should retrieve all the similar orders.

I have order id 1 having SKU A B C and item qty 1 1 2 respectively total 3 items. I need to select all the similar orders from the table. expected o/p: the query should retrieve orders with ids 1 and 4.

```
**orderTable**
id  order_date
1   2019-01-01
2   2019-01-02
3   2019-01-03
4   2019-01-04

**purchasedProductsTable**
orderId  sku     qty
1        A       1
1        B       1
1        C       2
2        A       1
3        B       1
4        A       1
4        B       1
4        C       2
```

Comment: I have a question for you. Why are you keeping a table (orderTable) with only one field id?

Comment: And why are you placing a comma after id, sku ?

Comment: i have edited now :)

Answer (score 1):

To select all records related to an order directly from purchase table:

`SELECT * FROM purchasedProductsTable WHERE orderId = 1;`

To select all records related to an order by joining orderTable:

`SELECT * FROM orderTable OT JOIN purchasedProductsTable PT ON (PT.orderId = OT.id) WHERE OT.id = 1;`

If you only need order 1 & 4:

`SELECT * FROM orderTable OT JOIN purchasedProductsTable PT ON (PT.orderId = OT.id) WHERE OT.id IN (1,4);`

Order by oldest order date first:

`SELECT * FROM orderTable OT JOIN purchasedProductsTable PT ON (PT.orderId = OT.id) ORDER BY OT.order_date DESC;`

Here is a [SQL Fiddle for demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a2918/4).

Comment: So do you got it fixed?

Comment: actually what i need is i should get the oldest order in the system which is not processed . and see the skus and item qty in that order and with that reference order i need to select all the similar orders. :) . lets say order 1 is created at first which is oldest unprocessed order. which has sku A B C and qty 1 1 2 which has total  item count of 3 (identical). so i should select all order which have skus A B C and item qty of 1 1 2 respectively..

Comment: Without a order date how can you get the oldest order? And can you please post your expected result

Comment: Does the results as expected to you? I have updated query

Comment: i need to be specific with the purchased items and with quantity too @Sinto :) that query will retrive all orders. thanks